# Готовая функция/класс для выявления мата php

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, по мере роста самописного проекта, как это часто бывает появляется нужда в использовании цензуры и запретов на использование определнных слов, так вот чтобы не изобретать заново велосипед так сказать, есть ли готовый класс/фукнция, с определением  всех матов и плохих слов, с учетом окончаний и тд,  в свободном доступе?  мне нужно лишь их найти в тексте, дальше там уже вывести соответствующее предупреждение я смогу реализовать сам, спасибо

Comment: Задача ни разу не банальна, всякие 6/\RTb вы 〉〈YN̆ выловите :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Класс для фильтрации нецензурных выражений (матов).
https://github.com/vearutop/php-obscene-censor-rus

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант: Создать словарь(без окончаний) а далее каждое сообщение сравнивать со словарем если содержится слово из словаря то выводить запрет

Comment: вот тоже думал об этом, но ведь задача настолько банальна, что неужели нигде нет готовых библиотек или массивов, странно) ладно попробую конечно сам, если не найду решение, спасибо

Comment: нет ну почему же, например в той же КС 1.6 стоят плагины на Анти-мат. Скачайте плагины я уверен что вместе с ним идет и словарь.